# How to remove the cms dashboard login page from a domain

Tags: security, concrete5

I have few domains that functioning under a single instance of the CMS.

www.domain.ru - russian
www.domain.com - english
www.domain.it - itally

The content editors working on the path: www.otherdomain.com/dashboard, this domain is limited for a certain url only.

but, I want to prevent people from accessing  www.domain.ru/dashboard or www.domain.com/dashboard.

Is the re anyway to do that? I just want to minimize the risk by trying to login with robots.

**Edit**
This is my css file

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a htaccess file to prevent access on your dashboard pages ?

Comment: Because it is a domain alias that is pointing to the domain www.otherdomain.com/ and this domain already has its own .htaccess file, Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how? I dont know how to handle certain domain in a shared .htaccess. Thanks

Comment: I can explain, but I need your htaccess file.

Comment: Have a look at htaccess + htpasswd files.